# Complex Queries in ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I've successfully set-up ELK stack. ELK gives me great insights on data. However, I'm not sure how I'll fetch the following result.

Let say, I've a column `user_id` and `action`. The values in action can be `installed` , `activated`, `engagement` and `click`. So, I want that if a particular user has performed an activity `installed` on 21 May and 21 June, then while fetching results for the month of June, ELK should not return those users who has already performed that activity earlier before. For eg, for the following table:-

```
Date    UserID      Activityin the previous month
1 May       1           Activated
3 May       2           Activated
6 May       1           Click
8 May       2           Activated
11 June     1           Activated
12 June     1           Activated
13 June     1           Click
```

User1 and User2 has activated on 1May and 3May respectively. User2 has also activated on 8May. So, when I filter the users for the month of May having activity `Activated`, it should return me count `2`, ie

```
   1 May        1           Activated
   3 May        2           Activated
```

User2 on 8May is being removed because it has performed that same activity before.

Now if I write the same query for the month of June, it should return me nothing, because the same users have perform the same activity earlier as well.

How can I write this query in ELK?

Answer (score 0):

This type of relational query is not possible with ElasticSearch.

You would need to add another column (FirstUserAction) and either populate it when the data is loaded, or schedule a task (in whatever scripting/programming language you're comfortable with) to periodically calculate and update the values for this column.